# Vimeo Video Autoplay in Popup

Tags: woocommerce

I want to play vimeo video with woocommerce gallery. When user click on thumbnail vimeo video autoplay in popup.Is there any solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'WooCommerce - Embed Videos To Product Image Gallery' to show videos in product gallery.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-embed-videos-to-product-image-gallery/

Comment: No there is different scenario which i have solved. WE want to show video on gallery slide and autoplay.
Thanks